# Big O under the integral / taylor expansion of likelilhood

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, probability-limit-theorems

Assume we have some fixed (finite, may be a density, but not necessarily) function
$f(x)$

and some other function $g(\theta,x)$ such that for fixed $x$, $g(\theta,x)$ is in $O(\theta^m)$.

Furthermore, assume a random variable $\delta_n$ such that $\delta_n \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} 0 $.
Is this enough to state that $\int f(x) g(\delta_n,x) dx  \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} 0$ ?

The specific situation where I have seen this argument was that $f(x) = p(\theta,x)$ for some fixed $\theta$ and $g(\theta,x)$ is the rest term of the taylor expansion of the respective log-likelihood $\ln p(\theta,x)$ around $\theta$, and it was not explained why this works. (And i couldn't figure out how to see it)

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer to my question:

Assume we can write $$g(\theta,x) = \theta^m h(x)$$ for some function $h$, which will be true in the above case of a Taylor expansion at $0$.

Then we have that $$\int f(x) g(\theta,x) dx = \theta^m \int f(x)h(x)dx$$

As long as $|\int f(x) h(x) dx| < \infty $, this is continuos in $\theta$ at $0$ , thus the claim follows by the continuos mapping theorem.